# Perplexity of Whitman

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

In section 26 of "Song of Myself", Whitman wrote:

> I hear the train’d soprano (what work with hers is this?)
>   The orchestra whirls me wider than Uranus flies,

Who knows the meaning of the sentence in parenthesis? *(what work with hers is this?)*

Comment: Sorry, poetry (or literary) analysis is off-topic.

Comment: Why? This is a simple English. And I didn't ask for analysis. I just asked for simple meaning of a simple English sentence.

Comment: It's long standing guideline that 'what does this mean?', especially poetry, lyrics, and jokes, is a poor question for ELU/SE because it is too opinion based. The author may have meant many things, and interpretations can go in many directions. It also requires a lot more context even if you had a very specific, objective question (eg who does 'her' refer to).

Comment: 'her' obviously refers to 'trained soprano' and needs no more context. I know you are talking about what, but in this case you are off-topic, not my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'What work with hers is this?' would perhaps be better read as: What work, with hers, is this?

I believe he is referring to the song being performed. The phrase suggests a feeling of wondering from the narrator. He asks (metaphorically) what work (piece of music) with her own work (singing) as accompaniment, is being played.

A more natural version for modern ears might be something as simple as 'What is this song?!'

Comment: Perfect. It was my first guess either. He is saying "which piece is going with her voice?".